# Are they semantically different?

Tags: phrase-meaning

1. say to sb
2. speak to sb
3. talk to sb

What's the exact difference in meaning among them?

Comment: Say requires an object; the others do not.

Comment: They basically mean the same thing, but if you're asking about some nuanced differences in meaning (for example, "John speaks to me" vs. "that painting speaks to me"), then you should really be more specific about the cause of your confusion, preferably with examples.

Comment: As Michael says, you have to 'say _something_ to somebody'. 'Talk to' probably implies a longer conversation than 'speak to', but it isn't a hard-and-fast rule.